# Javascript in a .txt file

Tags: javascript, php, date, client

I have a Javascript function to get the client side date as follows:

```js
var d = new Date();

var month = d.getMonth() + 1;

var thedate =
d.getDate() + "/" +
month + "/" + 
d.getFullYear() +
"  at  "
+ d.getHours() + ":" + 
(d.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + d.getMinutes();


document.write(thedate);
```

I need this in PHP though, so I tried using this:

```
$datevar = '
<script>
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var thedate = d.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear() + "  at  " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();
document.write(thedate);
</script>
';
```

The piece of code above works fine, **BUT** only if I `echo` it. I don't want to `echo` the code. I want to insert it into a log file. This is my code for the log file:

```
$log_file_name = '1.log'; 
file_put_contents("$log_file_name, $datevar"  , FILE_APPEND);
```

This returns with literally the code in the log, not the date and time. I would like it to come up with the date.

**Can I make it clear that I want the client's date, not the server's**

Please, can someone help me with this. I will accept any alternative way to get the client's current date and time. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use PHP instead to do that logic?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @Lixus As far I could tell, there is no way to use PHP to find the CLIENT's date/time

Comment: @Sirko I am pretty sure that returns in the server's time, not the client's time

Comment: In that case you need ajax to send the date to your php file

Comment: @Lixus How would I approach this?

Comment: You can not get the client's time without executing code on the client side.

Comment: If you are writing the script code in local file and even if you managed to execute it, it'll only going to return the server time since file is stored on the server. You'll have to execute the code on client side

Comment: @Sirko it will be executed on a webpage, so on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the client's time from the browser, then send that to the server with your form submit by adding the value to a hidden input.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="timestamp" name="timestamp" value="" />
```

Your JS will look like this:

```
<script>
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("timestamp").value = d.getTime() / 1000;
</script>
```

Your `time.php` file will look like this:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['timestamp'])) {
    $datevar = date('d/m/Y', $_POST['timestamp']) . ' at ' . date('h:i', $_POST['timestamp']) . PHP_EOL;
    $log_file_name = '1.log';
    file_put_contents($log_file_name, $datevar, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't know you could directly insert AJAX into PHP like you have.

Comment: You aren't.  The javascript is separate and should be included in a js file in the html, or in <script> tags on the html page, or worst case echo'd from PHP.

Comment: Sorry, That makes more sense

Comment: What will my form action be?

Comment: You don't need any form for this

Comment: My date and time are submitted along with lots of other variables in a form. How can I put this in a form?

Comment: So id of `timestamp` and name of `$("#timestamp").val(timestamp);`. Right? Like `<input id="timestamp" name="$("#timestamp").val(timestamp);">`

Comment: Nope still no date in .log file

Comment: Is my JS on time.php or on my HTML form page

Comment: It goes at the end of your HTML form page inside body tag